# What is the difference between the method of lagrange multipliers and penalty-based methods?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Both the method of Lagrange multipliers and penalty-based methods involve
converting a constrained optimization problem into an unconstrained one by
creating a new function $\mathcal{L}$ that penalizes $\mathcal{L}$ when the
constraint is violated. In both of these methods, the general form of
$\mathcal{L}$ is:

$$\mathcal{L} (\mathbf{x}, \lambda) = f (\mathbf{x}) + \lambda \cdot
   \varphi (h (\mathbf{x}))$$

where $f (\mathbf{x})$ is the objective function, $\varphi (h
(\mathbf{x}))$ is a penalty function of the constraint, and $\lambda$ is
some parameter.

In the case of the method of lagrange multipliers, $\varphi (h (\mathbf{x}))
= h (\mathbf{x})$, whereas in penalty-based methods, $\varphi$ is usually
chosen to be the square function. Aside from the choice of $\varphi$, I don't
see the difference between the two methods.

Answer (score 1):

Penalty methods are algorithmic. Given a suitable $\lambda_k$, our aim is to minimize the objective function $ \mathbf{x}_k= \arg\min f (\mathbf{x}) + \lambda_k \cdot \varphi (h (\mathbf{x}))$. Eventually, the sequence $\{\lambda_k, \mathbf{x}_k\}$ converges to a local minimum. The Lagrange multipliers method is global, and under some regularity conditions involving $ \{f (\mathbf{x}), h (\mathbf{x})\}$, we can determine all stationary points, that need further qualification.